# Do you have to print the FMM when crossing into Mexico overland?

Tags: mexico, fmm-tourist-card

I'm traveling to Tijuana soon overland and will obtain [an FMM as per the legal requirement](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159564/does-a-french-with-us-green-card-need-a-mexico-s-visitor-visa-fmm-when-enterin?noredirect=1&lq=1). However its no clear if there's an obligation to actually print it out or if I can show it on my phone. Do the rules ever clearly state this for land crossings?

Comment: Per your linked Q&A, the FMM must be stamped at the border, so you can't just show it on your phone

Comment: @Midavalo sure but perhaps they'll just print it out for you at the border station?

Comment: @JonathanReez  I haven't seen anyone printing anything or getting some non-passport paper getting stamped at the land border. So I wouldn't count on them printing anything, though I haven't asked for it so I may be incorrect.

Comment: @JonathanReez, If printing it is a problem you can always just fill in the card at the border station at the cost of a couple of minutes. The biggest advantage of the online application may be when you're staying long enough to need to pay since, if you don't pay in advance, you likely need to pay at a Mexican bank and bring the receipt back to immigration for the stamp (I'm not positive about that, but that is how it works for all other immigration payments).

Answer (score 8):

I've had a quick look at a handful of Mexico tourist help websites, and all of them mention printing your online FMM and receipts.  One of them specifically says "you must print" and none of them give the impression that it can be just shown on a device etc.

> You’ll receive an acceptance email that you must print and bring with you to get stamped at the border.

- https://wheretheroadforks.com/the-mexico-fmm-tourist-permit-explained/
- https://www.bajabound.com/before/permits/onlineFMM
- https://www.mexperience.com/your-mexican-tourist-permit-fmm/

And Dennis has commented with a link to the official INM (Mexico Immigration) website FMM application page which also states that the form should be printed

> The applicant shall print and bring the FMM to the facility aimed for
> the international transit of persons where he/she wishes to enter
> through.

- https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html

Comment: Perhaps a more authoritative source, [the government application web site](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html) also says to print it.

Comment: @Dennis thanks, I'll update my answer